# Python : Cross_val_score - weird scoring results

Tags: python, cross-validation

I use Oython and the "cross_val_score" function to mesure performance of a LogisticRegression modelfor a classification task (Yes/No) 
I observe that when using scoring = 'accuracy' and scoring = 'recall_weighted', I have exactly the same results (I made several tests) :

```
X = data.iloc[:,0:2]
y = data.iloc[:,2]



model = LogisticRegression(class_weight = {'Y':7,'N':3} )
model.fit(X,y)
scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=10, scoring = 'recall_weighted')

scores
array([ 0.81818182,  1.        ,  0.90909091,  1.        ,  1.        ,
    1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.66666667,  0.33333333])


scores_accuracy = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=10, scoring = 'accuracy')
scores_accuracy 
array([ 0.81818182,  1.        ,  0.90909091,  1.        ,  1.        ,
    1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.66666667,  0.33333333])
```

Have you got the same things with your datasets ?
Can you help me ?

Thanks you,

Regards,

Lionel

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the weighted recall is turning out out to be mathematically same as accuracy.

This is probably not about the cross validation. You could check other data sets, or same, and compute the scores without using cross_val_score and see if the accuracy is still same as weighted recall

Comment: Hi @Sachit Nagpal

Comment: Hi @Sachit Nagpal , thanks you for your response. How can I compute the scores without using cross_val_score. ? Lionel

Comment: Hi @Sachit Nagpal, you're right, in deed, it's not about the cross validation. I performed some tests with other data sets without cross validation, and the weighted recall and accuracy are strictly and systematically equal. Mathematically these two things are not the same : weighted recall = tp/(tp+fn)  +  tn/(tn+fp ) and accuracy = (tp+tn)/(tp+tn+fp+fn). So I think there is an error in sklearn. Moreover I performed calculation on Rapidminer (a machine learning software) and accuracy and weighted recall are not equal.

Comment: okay. interesting and surprising to know. but helpful to now know the same. regards